# Type mismatch: inferred type is Dp but CardElevation was expected in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-card

Started learning Jetpack Compose. An error occurred: Type mismatch: inferred type is Dp but CardElevation was expected, I can't understand what the problem is, tell me how to solve it.
[image]

import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp library imported, and updated versions of Jetpack Compose, expected to help

Answer (score 14):

If you are using Material 3, then you need to use CardElevation in this way:

```
elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(defaultElevation = 5.dp)
```

More details [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#Card(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.material3.CardColors,androidx.compose.material3.CardElevation,androidx.compose.foundation.BorderStroke,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,kotlin.Function1))